# Overbraces on the same vertical height

Tags: equations, align, overbrace

Happy lockdown,

Hope we are all not going insane yet.

Just a quick one - I have the following code - I am trying to ensure that the overbraces are at the same vertical height - any idea how I do this? At the moment they are fixed to each term (see image attached).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\begin{document} 

\begin{equation}
    \overbrace{\frac{\delta (\rho k)}{\delta t}}^\text{Time} +
    \overbrace{\triangledown (\rho U k)}^\text{Convection} =
    \overbrace{\triangledown [(\mu + \frac{\mu\textsubscript{t}}{\sigma \textsubscript{k}}) \triangledown \epsilon]}^\text{Diffusion} + \overbrace{P\textsubscript{k} + P\textsubscript{b} + \rho \epsilon + S\textsubscript{k}}^\text{Sources/sinks}
    \label{eqn:transport1}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help, much appreciated.

Josh [image]

Comment: Sorry am new to this - have done.

Comment: Note that `\text` might not be the macro you want to use here (though one can argue that it is). See what happens if you add `\itshape` to the text before `\begin{equation}`. Then the contents of `\text` is also italic, which might or might not be what you expected (sadly many users does not know when to and when not to use  the `\text` command)

Comment: Just remove the command. My point was just to show that the text command doesn't just provide upright text as many think it does and thus uses the text command everywhere

Comment: Have done it now, 12,000 word diss so put it in a few times!!

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you insert a typographic strut in overbrace expressions 2, 3, and 4. The strut itself may be constructed via

```
\newcommand\mystrut{\smash[b]{\vphantom{\frac{()}{\delta}}}}
```

i.e., it simply captures the full height of `\frac{()}{\delta}`.

Oh, and I would replace all instances of `\triangledown` with `\nabla`, and I would also increase the size of the round parentheses and square brackets in the third overbrace term. And, do please make a habit out of encasing the term after `^` in the overbrace constructs in a pair of curly braces. Finally, I must confess to not "getting" why you use text mode instead of math mode for the subscript letters.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\mystrut{\smash[b]{\vphantom{\frac{()}{\delta}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eqn:transport1}
    {\overbrace{\frac{\delta (\rho k)}{\delta t}}^{\text{Time}}} 
    +
    {\overbrace{\nabla(\rho U k)\mystrut}^{\mathclap{\text{Convection}}}}
    =
    {\overbrace{\nabla\Bigl[\Bigl(\mu + \frac{\mu_t}{\sigma_k}\Bigr) 
                \nabla\epsilon\Bigr]\mystrut}^{\text{Diffusion}}}
    +
    {\overbrace{P_k + P_b + \rho \epsilon + S_k\mystrut}^{\text{Sources/sinks}}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)